# How to convert a list [a,b] to [[a],[b]] in Python? A one line function something like map

Tags: python, list

I want a single line function to convert a list into group of list.
Something like ["a","b"] to [["a"],["b"]]
I know this works:

```
lists = ["a","b"]
newList = []
for i in lists: newList.append([i])
```

But want something like map function

Comment: Something like `[[x] for x in lists]`?

Comment: If you're looking for 'something like map function', take a look at `reduce()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
lists = [[i] for i in lists]
```